# How do I transfer my current Ubuntu system (primarily data) from my old computer to my new computer?

Tags: boot, usb

My new computer is a BMAX B8 Pro mini PC with 1TB SSD storage (same storage size as my old PC). I have installed Linux 21 and it functions as expected. I have followed directions from some YouTube videos to create a bootable USB drive from my old PC which runs Linux 21, and modified the boot sequence to start from the USB drive. So far, no luck.

Comment: "Linux 21"? Which supported Ubuntu release is that? I have Ubuntu-specific answers, but I'm not sure they apply to "Linux 21".

Comment: I suspect they mean Mint 21.

Comment: Any Ubuntu release from 2021 (ie. 21.04 from 2021-April or 21.10 from 2021-October) is EOL & thus off-topic on this system unless the question is specific to helping you move to a *supported* release of Ubuntu; but 21 is very unclear as no Ubuntu release uses 21 as its year/version number.